# Define factories for User and Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have app with `users` and `roles`, with a `users_roles` table for the relation. I'm trying to define factories for `User` and `Role` models:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Test User'
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'changeme'
    password_confirmation 'changeme'
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    # confirmed_at Time.now
  end

    factory :role do 
        name 'user'
    end
end
```

and my test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  before (:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @user.role = FactoryGirl.create(:role)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET 'show'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get :show, :id => @user.id
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should find the right user" do
      get :show, :id => @user.id
      assigns(:user).should == @user
    end

  end

end
```

model

```
  private
  def default_role
    self.roles << Role.where(:name => 'user').first
  end
```

and when i run rspec, i've got an error

```
Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
   Role(#68298640) expected, got NilClass(#14882680)
 # ./app/models/user.rb:33:in `default_role'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by the time `User.default_role` was called, the new `Role` had not been created yet.

Just change the test to the following:

```
  before (:each) do
    role = FactoryGirl.create(:role)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @user.roles << role
    sign_in @user
  end
```

Comment: got `undefined method role=' for #<User` when `@user.role = role`

Comment: got `undefined method each' for #<Role` when `@user.roles = role`

Comment: yep, now tests are passing well